# How can I find out what CSS is needed to implement twitter Bootstraps Modal.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use twitter bootstraps modal popup. I have this all working fine with the full bootstrap.css file my problem is that I do you want to use it all. I just want the core CSS for the popup modal. Is there a way I can find out what is needed with out going trough all 4000 lines or so and working it out?

I have tried customising the download and included just the modal but CSS in that file did not make it work.

Comment: You say that like its hard to go look at the source and find the file named "modal":  https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/modals.less

Comment: Like I said in the question I tried using the modal CSS of there site but that alone did not work. I wanted to know what other CSS was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the Chrome browser, right click the modal and 'inspect it'. From there on the bottom in the right hand column you'll see all the CSS that makes up that modal and you can just copy that. As for the Javascript part of it you'll need to take a look in the Bootstrap js file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try  CSS Dust-Me:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

This finds all unused CSS, and then you can remove it manually....